# What is {} mark at constructors in Flutter and Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

My code :

```
 class aaa {
     String a ;
     aaa.n1({String a1}){  // erase {} here.No error  
    // aaa.n1(String a1){  // No error
         this.a = a1 ;
         print(a1) ;
     }
  }

 class bbb extends aaa {
   bbb.n1(String uu) : super.n1('y') ; //compile and error here (at 'y' letter)
 }

void main() {
   bbb a = new bbb.n1('hhhhhhhh');
   print(a.a);
}
```

The error : Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
  bbb.n1(String uu) : super.n1('y') ;

I imitate at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html like that

Center({Key key, double widthFactor, double heightFactor, Widget child })

Why do they use {} mark . Doesn't it ({}) meaning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{}` is used for named arguments, which means you have to specify the argument name to which you want to specify the value.

In the below code the name is `a1` and the value is `y`.

```
class bbb extends aaa {
   bbb.n1(String uu) : super.n1(a1: 'y') ; //compile and error here (at 'y' letter)
}
```

Comment: It is important to mention that arguments inside the {} are optional and you can set default values Wie adding = and the default after the argument name.